# Union different columns from the same table using a data step

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I would like to turn the following MWE into a data step (possibly using a macro) so I can run it with six years worth of data, and five or six columns of data. Here the years are pre-defined variables.

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE SASUSER.OUT_DATA AS 
       SELECT  &YEAR1 AS YEAR,
               ID,
               ROUND(ANN_TURN&YEAR1) AS ANN_TURN,
               ROUND(ANN_PROF&YEAR1) AS ANN_PROF
 FROM WORK.IN_DATA
    WHERE ANN_TURN&YEAR1 IS NOT MISSING OR
          ANN_PROF&YEAR1 IS NOT MISSING
 UNION
       SELECT &YEAR2 AS YEAR,
              ID,
              ROUND(ANN_TURN&YEAR2) AS ANN_TURN,
              ROUND(ANN_PROF&YEAR2) AS ANN_PROF
 FROM WORK.IN_DATA
    WHERE ANN_TURN&YEAR2 IS NOT MISSING OR
          ANN_PROF&YEAR2 IS NOT MISSING
 UNION 
    SELECT  &YEAR3 AS YEAR,
            ID,
            ROUND(ANN_TURN&YEAR3) AS ANN_TURN,
            ROUND(ANN_PROF&YEAR3) AS ANN_PROF
    FROM WORK.IN_DATA
        WHERE ANN_TURN&YEAR3 IS NOT MISSING OR
              ANN_PROF&YEAR3 IS NOT MISSING;
   QUIT;
```

Example of IN_DATA (apologies I'm not sure how to add a table in correct format):

```
ID ANN_TURN_Y1819 ANN_TURN_Y1920 ANN_TURN_Y2021  ANN_PROF_Y1819 ANN_PROF_Y1920 ANN_PROF_Y2021 

1  100 110 120 10 12 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DATA Step `SET` statement is used to *stack* data sets.

However, your SQL is performing a UNION of selections from the same data set, essentially reshaping the data through a transposition.

If you are ROUNDing for display purposes, use a FORMAT instead.
The WHERE clause might be suspect. OR'ing double negatives always made this old head wobble.

Example:

You can do this in a non-macro way using `VVALUEX` to extract the value of a dynamically named variable.

```
data have;
  do companyid = 1 to 1000;
    array ann_turn ann_turn1920-ann_turn2025;
    array ann_prof ann_prof1920-ann_prof2025;

    do over ann_turn ;
      x + 1;  ann_turn = x;
      y + 10; ann_prof = y;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  keep companyid ann_turn: ann_prof: ;
run;

%let years_list = 1920, 1940, 1961, 1962, 1991 to 1995, 2009;

data want(keep=companyid year ann_turn ann_prof);
  set have;
  do year = &years_list;
    ann_turn = input(vvaluex(cats('ANN_TURN', year)),best16.);
    ann_prof = input(vvaluex(cats('ANN_PROF', year)),best16.);
    output;
  end;
  format ann_: dollar 15.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to use predefined variables as the years, but 
 array years &year1 &year2 &year3 ;
gives me an error. Do I need a comma separator?

To expand, the variables in in_data are named ANN_TURN1819, ANN_TURN1920, ANN_TURN2021 etc. I have specified the names as year1 = 1819 and so on.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of `in_data`.

Comment: I have added an example. Does the answer above include somewhere to define the input table?

Comment: This answer includes a step to make an example input dataset it calls HAVE.  So replace HAVE in the second step with the name of your input dataset.